# Summing by common strings in different files (bash)

Tags: linux, string, bash, sum

I have a **file1** with the amount of times a user shows up in the files, something like this:

```
4 userC
2 userA
1 userB
```

and I have another **file2** with users and other info like:

```
userC, degree2
userA, degree1
userB, degree2
```

and I want an **output** where it shows the amount of times users show up for each degree:

```
5 degree2
2 degree1
```

Comment: some awk's but i don't really know how to use it, and tryind to use diff

Comment: you have to add your code to your question

Comment: You will use two **associative arrays** (bash > 4) utilizing the `user` as the `key` in each. You will use one `while read..` loop to populate each array (two total). Once populated, you are free to query the arrays as needed. Also, please read the [**About**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) page soon and also visit the link describing [**How to Ask a Question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). Providing the necessary details, including your code, and associated errors, if any, will allow everyone here to help you with your question.

Comment: Presumably, the commas in `file2` are there just to make life difficult?

Answer (score 0):

I agree that associative arrays would be a good option, as long as you use a late version of bash. Otherwise, this would fix it:

```
cat file1 | while read score name
do
    if f2=`egrep "^$name," file2`
    then
            hit=`echo "$f2" | awk -F, '{ print $2 }'`
            echo "$score $hit"
    fi
done
```

Be very careful with the characters, in particular get the backticks after f2= and hit= correct!